# How to Output text before thread sleeps in a timer?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
     private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (...)
                    {
                        string sieg = "...";

                    {
                        richTextBox1.Text = sieg;
                    }    

                    if (...)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        Application.Exit();
                    }
                }
                    if (...)
                    {
                        string lose = "...";
                        richTextBox1.Text = lose;

                        if (...)
                        {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                        Application.Exit();
                        }

}
```

I dot unimportant lines
My problem is the following as I give something out in RichTextbox then go for a few seconds into a sleep and then I finish the program the whole takes place in a timer... My problem is that he goes into sleep before he has made the output in the Richtextbox
I'm new to Windows Forms programming and don't know how to finish something clean vlt you can help me
Please don't make it too complicated for me to comprehend.
Is it possible to wait for a user interaction if I show a text box and wait until a button is pressed?
If I solve this with a button I would still have to stop the timer because I have 2 Pictureboxes in it which I move in a loop.
Or I'll have to stop the picture boxing. Maybe you can think of something.

Greetings S
Sorry for my Bad Eng

Comment: Don't block the UI thread.

Comment: Youre Funny i search a Better way... that i dont have to Block the Thread

Comment: Use `await Task.Delay()`

Answer (score 0):

Use a secondary timer.

```
private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (...)
                {
                    string sieg = "...";

                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = sieg;
                }    

                if (...)
                {
                    timer2.Interval = 1000;
                    timer2.Enabled = true;
                    timer2.Start();
                }
            }
                if (...)
                {
                    string lose = "...";
                    richTextBox1.Text = lose;

                    if (...)
                    {
                        timer2.Interval = 10000;
                        timer2.Enabled = true;
                        timer2.Start();
                    }

}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```